# Double integral to evaluate

Tags: calculus

Given the following function: $k(x,t) = (1-x)t$ for $x>t$ and $k(x,t) = (1-t)x$ for $x<t$ I would like to evaluate the following integral:
$$
I = \int_0^1\int_0^1|k(x,t)|^2dxdt
$$
I should definitely be able to do this (I even know the answer: 1/90) but I am failing at it. Could someone give me a tip about how to evaluate this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the square of integration as  two triangles along $x=t$ line, one region $x>t$ and other region $t>x$ 
$$ \int_0^{1}\int_0^t ((1-x)t)^2 dx dt + \int_0^{1}\int_0^x ((1-t)x)^2 dt dx  $$
[image]

Comment: If I evaluate the integral this way I get 19/90, which is not correct. I am fairly certain I have evaluated it correctly. What is wrong? (It should be 1/90)

Comment: @Erik how did you evaluate it? I am getting 1/90 from [mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[Integrate[%28%281+-+x%29+t%29^2%2C+{t%2C+0%2C+x}]%2C+{x%2C+0%2C+1}]+%2B+++Integrate[Integrate[%28%281+-+t%29+x%29^2%2C+{x%2C+0%2C+t}]%2C+{t%2C+0%2C+1}])

Answer (score 0):

Break the integral up into 2:

$$  \int_0^1 dx \: \int_x^1 |(1-t)x |^2 +  \int_0^1 dx \: \int_0^x |(1-x)t |^2 $$

Evaluating these double integrals produces the desired result.  A hint: this is equal to

$$ \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 dx [x^2 (1-x)^3 + x^3 (1-x)^2] $$

Expand the binomials and evaluate.

Comment: I agree with the second term in the second equation, the first term I am not sure is correct. Furthermore, I get 8/45 after evaluating the integrals. (It should be 1/90)

Comment: I got $1/90$; so did Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F3+integrate+%28x%5E2+%281-x%29%5E3+%2B+x%5E3+%281-x%29%5E2%29+%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Function $k(x,\,t)$ takes the same values over and under line $t=x.$